# What is the probability that two samples from a source have no overlap?

Tags: probability, self-study, sampling, combinatorics, hypergeometric-distribution

I picked 29 results from a list of 429 results. I then picked a second group of 27 (with replacement) results from the same list of 429. There was no overlap between the two samples. What is the probability of this?

I'm sure it's a simple question, I know there are similar question asked, but I haven't managed to apply them to my exact question. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is there a typo in your question ? 429 or 492 ?

Comment: Answers to this question are available by linking through the [tag:hypergeometric] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the initial number of results be $N = 429$. We draw $m=29$ results in the first trial. We then draw and $k=27$ results (with replacement). We get no 'overlap' in results if we choose the $k$ results from ones other than $m$ which is $N-m$

The probability that the results don't overlap is  $\frac{{N-m}\choose{k}}{{N}\choose{k}}=\frac{{429-29}\choose{27}}{{429}\choose{27}}=0.1420$

Comment: It would help to *explain* the formula, for otherwise it is of little general use.

Comment: Thank you very kindly for the help!